# Unable to boot windows 8 after ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, boot-failure, windows-8

I just got my new notebook with windows 8 pre installed. After installing ubuntu 12.04 when I try to boot windows 8 it says "**Automated Recovery in Progress**" which fails afterwards and shuts down the machine stating the **partition on which windows is installed is locked.**

Actually during the ubuntu installation I merged two disk drives to one and made it as an extended partition. Then I divided the extended partition into two logical partition. One of which is blank and other is having Ubuntu installed.

I had tried to back up the data from ubuntu but I was not able to see the files of the partition containing windows 8.

Please help me to recover windows 8 or to back up the data.

```
Output of sudo fdisk -l

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *        2048      718847      358400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          718848   478152703   238716928   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       478154750  1465147391   493496321    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       478154752   687869951   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       687872000  1465147391   388637696    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Can you list all of the partitions on your hard drive with `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: kelvinafox, it displays all the partitions in ubuntu but I am not able to access the data of windows partion, it shows it as a blank partition.

Comment: disabled UEFI? secure boot?  merged two drives, including windows 8 partition? Preinstalled windows generally have two partition, recovery and windows 8.. you merged them and created new partition? more details...

Comment: codeomnitrix, what I meant to say was: Can you run that command and add it in either a comment or to your original post so we can see it?

Comment: Thanks, Web-E and kelvinafox, need to check on that, will update in some time

Comment: this may help you - http://superuser.com/questions/487348/how-can-i-get-back-in-to-locked-partition

Comment: web-e i really don't want to format, is there any other option available without formatting.

Comment: kelvinafox, updated the post to contain the output, does this gives clarification.

Comment: that link was not for formatting, it was to recover. Probably partition table is corrupted. I got this `Note for NTFS Users / Users of Runtime Software products
Products from Runtime Software will occasionally erroneously report NTFS disks as containing SFS partitions. This is either due to NTFS having trashed its partition information and writing a random partition ID into the partition table that happens to match the one for SFS, or more likely bugs in the Runtime Software products, since this issue has only ever come up with their software.`-http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/sfs/

Comment: also you can try `testdisk`or any other bootable software to scan for lost partition table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mess. Strange things about your installation, some of which could be causing problems, include:

- A computer that shipped with Windows 8 should boot in EFI mode and use the GUID Partition Table (GPT), but your disk is clearly using the older Master Boot Record (MBR) partitions. This suggests that you converted from GPT to MBR, which would render Windows unbootable.
- Your MBR partition table clearly shows that your Windows installation uses the Windows Logical Disk Manager (LDM) configuration, aka "dynamic disks." This is Microsoft's equivalent to the Linux Logical Volume Manager (LVM), but the two technologies are different in detail and therefore incompatible. If you converted from standard partitions to LDM before installing Linux, then resizing operations by the Linux partitioner could have done serious damage to the LDM setup, making Windows quite unhappy.
- As a sub-point of the former, I'm not at all sure that it's advisable to mix LDM partitions with conventional partitions on a single disk.

The easiest solution at this point is probably to wipe the partition table and re-install everything from scratch. This may be considerably less easy if you lack Windows installation media, though, or if you've got personal data in the Windows setup that you want to rescue. If either of those is the case, you might want to post a question to a Windows forum about recovery prior to repairing the setup.

Sorry I can't offer a simple and easy solution. If there is such a solution, I don't know what it is. I can think of a number of ways to proceed short of wiping your partition table, but they're all risky. For instance, you could use a Windows tool like [EaseUS Partition Manager](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) to try to convert back from LDM to conventional partitions, then either convert from MBR to GPT (if I'm right that Windows originally booted in EFI mode) or try to get Windows booting from a non-LDM MBR setup.

In the future, ***do not*** use Windows partitioning tools to prepare a disk for use with Linux. (That's one common way to dig yourself into an LDM hole.)